# base64'ing a sha1

Tags: c#, base64

Why does C#'s tobase64string convert "a46fb104c5ea2fd65df3909f4c6ba4191c2eb4e5" into a 56 character string while the following site: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en produced the base64 encoded string I'm trying to achieve? This is driving me effing insane! Haha.

Comment: Show us your C# code. Your comment has at least two eyebrow-raising phrases.

Comment: I will after work but basically, I'm following the websocket article on wikipedia and while I'm getting all of the other results as expected (including parsing the request key and appending the "magic number" to the end) the SHA1 value (once stripped of dashes) produces the a46fb.... number. I'm then passing that value to Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)) which produces a 56 character value and not the 28 bit like the wikipedia article has.

Comment: I have a feeling that the byte value is off...can't believe I didn't realize it before....I'm looking for a 28 digit base64 and 56/2=28 lol.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it to a byte array first.

Comment: I am. The sha1 returns the byte array which I do a replace on to remove the dashes, then I pass it to the base64 convert function via Encoding.UTF8(i've tried ASCII an several others).GetBytes(...).